# jQuery ui two checkboxes on checked need button to activate and on unchecked disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, checkbox

[Visit my fiddle first](http://jsfiddle.net/v5zRs/)

I am using jQuery-ui button set here. What I want when both `check-boxes` are checked I need the buttons to be activate and removeClass `disabledButton`, and when not checked (both) I want the buttons to be disabled and addClass `disabledButton`. How can I do that?

Here is my jQuery approach:

```
$(".conditionCheck").buttonset();    
$(".conditions").click(function () {    
  if ($(".conditions").is(':checked')) {   
    $(".paymentButton").removeAttr("disabled")
      .removeClass("disabledButton");   
  }    
  if (!$(".conditions").is(':checked')) {   
    $(".paymentButton").attr("disabled")
      .addClass("disabledButton");    
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$('.conditions').not(':checked').length` to get the number of unchecked controls. If this number is 0 then both have been checked, so you know what to do.

```
$(".conditions").click(function () {
  if ($('.conditions').not(':checked').length) {
    $(".paymentButton").prop("disabled", true).addClass("disabledButton");
  }
  else {
    $(".paymentButton").prop("disabled", false).removeClass("disabledButton");
  }
});
```

I have also changed the [incorrect use of `attr`](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#attr-versus-prop-) to disable the elements with `prop` which is the appropriate way.

The above code can also be written more concisely as

```
var allChecked = $('.conditions').not(':checked').length == 0;
$(".paymentButton").prop("disabled", !allChecked)
                   .toggleClass("disabledButton", !allChecked);
```